# "Liking" a musician or other artist

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, verbos

The verb `gustar`, when used with people, conveys a romantic interest (e.g. `Ella me gusta.` -> `I have a crush on her.`). How then, can you convey that you like a musician's music or an artist's paintings, for example, without romantic overtones? For example:

> I like Enrique Iglesias.
>
> I love Van Gogh!
>
> I really like Ricky Martin.

Would this simply be understood from the context as it is in English? Or is there a better option than `gustarle` and `encantarle`. I made this mistake recently when, after being asked what I liked about a particular country, I answered:

> Me gusta la gente aquí.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all: the meaning of *gustar* goes well beyond the romantic interest. This is something you have to bear in mind.

If we see the [RAE dictionary definition of *gustar*](http://www.rae.es/gustar), we get these meanings (*acepciones*):

> 1. tr. Sentir y percibir el sabor de las cosas.
> 2. tr. experimentar (‖ probar).
> 3. **intr. Agradar, parecer bien.**
> 4. **intr. Dicho de una persona: Resultar atractiva a otra.**
> 5. intr. Desear, querer y tener complacencia en algo. Gustar DE correr, DE jugar.

I've written with bold text the two meanings we have to understand clearly.

As you say, when referring to people *gustar* has a meaning related to romantic interest, but depending on the context, you may be talking about the art or the production of someone. When you say:

> Me gusta van Gogh

if you are talking about art, then the meaning will refer to the third meaning of gustar; but if there are (for example) two women talking about how handsome are/were some artists, then the meaning will be the fourth one.

---

The verb *encantar* has a stronger meaning than *gustar*:

> *Me **gusta** la pintura de van Gogh*  →  (yes, I like it, I think his paintings are beautiful).
>   *Me **encanta** la pintura de van Gogh*  →  (I'm really a fanatic of his art).

---

Regarding the troubles you had when you said "*Me gusta la gente aquí.*", I think it may depend on the context and the place where you said it.

First of all, I think that the right way to say that is:

> *Me gusta la gente **de** aquí*.

The context is very important because you need to be sure the people you talk to understand you're using *gustar* regarding its third meaning (see above) and not regarding to its fourth one.

To avoid any misunderstanding, in such a situation you could prefer something like:

> *Encuentro muy agradable (a) la gente de este lugar/ciudad/país*.

Comment: +1 Nice answer Nicolás! Quite complete!